# Why getBoundingClientRect returns zero coordinates?

Tags: javascript, svg

There is a function that returns `getBoundingClientRect` of HTML element:

```
export function getCoords(elem: Element) {
  var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  return {
    top: box.top + pageYOffset,
    left: box.left + pageXOffset,
    right: box.right + pageXOffset,
    bottom: box.bottom + pageYOffset,
    width: box.width,
    height: box.height,
    diagonal: Math.sqrt(box.width ** 2 + box.height ** 2)
  };
}
```

There is a SVG file with `<path id="r12">`:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-183.800 -755.650 1975.150 839.600">
   <g>
            <path id="r12" d="M385.325,-98.250 385.325,-26.300 273.075,-24.400 273.075,-153.175 385.325,-153.575 385.325,-101.325z"/>
            <path d="M316.975,-89.000 341.450,-89.000"/>
            <text x="325.575" y="-90.850" font-size="17">3</text>
            <text x="316.575" y="-73.925" font-size="17">22.0</text>
         </g>
</svg>
```

I retrieve this path element by id:

```
const el = svg.querySelector("#r12");
```

Then I try to get bounding:

```
if(el) const coords = getCoords(el);
```

It always returns me:

```
bottom: 0
diagonal: 0
height: 0
left: 0
right: 0
top: 0
width: 0
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Sorry, it is typo. I edited this in question\

Comment: `document.querySelector("#r12")` not `svg.querySelector("#r12")`

Comment: Are you sure this is the only element with this `id`? Ids **must** be unique per documents, foreign  elements like inline svg do not create a new document instance, so even your svg elements must not share their id with any other element in the document.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to be 100% sure the element exists in the DOM before you query its properties.

FYI, `id` values become **global** variables in every browser; so `getCoords(r12)` just works

Note: In SO snippets, the JavaScript runs **after** the DOM is created (onload/DOMContentloaded events)

```js
function getCoords(elem) {
  var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    top: box.top + pageYOffset,
    left: box.left + pageXOffset,
    right: box.right + pageXOffset,
    bottom: box.bottom + pageYOffset,
    width: box.width,
    height: box.height,
    diagonal: Math.sqrt(box.width ** 2 + box.height ** 2)
  };
}

console.log(getCoords(r12));
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-183.800 -755.650 1975.150 839.600">
  <g>
    <path id="r12" d="M385.325,-98.250 385.325,-26.300 273.075,-24.400 273.075,-153.175 385.325,-153.575 385.325,-101.325z"/>
    <path d="M316.975,-89.000 341.450,-89.000"/>
    <text x="325.575" y="-90.850" font-size="17">3</text>
    <text x="316.575" y="-73.925" font-size="17">22.0</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use: `svg.querySelector("#r12");` to access to your path property.

According to MDN, the command is: `document.querySelector("#r12");` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: I use it because I want to set from which elmenet start to search

Comment: You can also specify a base element for `querySelector`, but if you don't have it, you need to use the `document` element given that it's the root element.